# Using flutter how to use more than one firebase realtime database in the same App

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, flutter

We are developing an application in flutter using firebase realtime database, to provide several services for different customers. I would like to have a different database for each customer using the same firebase project. As firebase support multiple database in the same project I believe is possible to implement using FirebaseDatase plugin.

I tried to set a reference to the secondary database, but I can’t find a settle commando to change the instance for this database. If you are using Java or other language that uses Firebase SDK this is very simple, but I can't find a way using Flutter.

```
Future<DataSnapshot> getDbData(String dbChildPath) async {
DataSnapshot _objdatabase;
try {
  await FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .reference()
      .child(dbChildPath)
      .once()
      .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    _objdatabase = snapshot;
    print(_objdatabase.toString());
  });
  return _objdatabase;
} catch (erroDB) {
  print(erroDB);
  return null;
}}
```

My code is getting data from de default database.

How do I set the URL for the secondary database instance?

Please any idea?

Answer (score 5):

You can use parameters for FirebaseDatabase() as below :

```
String fdbUrl1 = "https://my-firebase-db-1.firebaseio.com"
String fdbUrl2 = "https://my-firebase-db-2.firebaseio.com"

final databaseReference1 = FirebaseDatabase(databaseURL:fdbUrl1).instance.reference();
final databaseReference2 = FirebaseDatabase(databaseURL:fdbUrl2).instance.reference();
```

Note : The above is not unit tested. It should work. Just in case not, add 'app' parameter of the constructor.

Comment: FYI : The firebase_database.dart says - /// If [app] is specified, its options should include a [databaseURL].

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would be to have your customer id in your children path, like:

```
await FirebaseDatabase.instance
  .reference()
  .child(customer_id)
  .child(dbChildPath)
  .once()
  .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
```

Although this is not a single DB for each customer.