# how to change firebase predefined realtime database in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I have the following problem, in a flutter project connected to firebase and I use the database in real time everything worked correctly until today I found myself needing to change the BD reference
that is to say in firebase now I have 2 BD **"https://debug.firebaseio.com"** and **"https://release.firebaseio.com"**
now my problem is that I can't change the reference so that it points to the new bd, it just grabs me
the old one that is selected by default
already try this `_dbRef = FirebaseDatabase(databaseURL:"https://debug.firebaseio.com").reference ();`
and also try doing manual configuration:

```
FirebaseApp firebaseApp = await FirebaseApp.configure (
    name: 'dbDebug',
    options: FirebaseOptions (
      googleAppID: '$ googleId',
      apiKey: '$ apiKey',
      projectID: '$ projectId',
      databaseURL: 'https://debug.firebaseio.com',
    )
  );
```

and then pass it the parameter _dbRef = new FirebaseDatabase (app: firebaseApp).reference ()
but in the end it still points to the default firebase db.
Has anyone come across something similar and solved it?

// I tried this answer in the following question [Using flutter how to use more than one firebase realtime database in the same App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57318094/using-flutter-how-to-use-more-than-one-firebase-realtime-database-in-the-same-ap)
// but now I can't use .instance after FirebaseDatabase ()

```
String fdbUrl1 = "https://my-firebase-db-1.firebaseio.com"
String fdbUrl2 = "https://my-firebase-db-2.firebaseio.com"

final databaseReference1 = FirebaseDatabase (databaseURL: fdbUrl1) .instance.reference ();
final databaseReference2 = FirebaseDatabase (databaseURL: fdbUrl2) .instance.reference ();
```

pubspec.yaml

firebase_core: 0.4.5
firebase_database: ^ 3.1.6